# Simple click and hit flash game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to create a simple game like whack a mole, what I want is for instead of mole make rectangle appear and disappear quickly on screen and the player has to click it more rectangles he click more his score increases.

I think it's a fairly simple game but my problem is:

How do I `make the rectangles appear and disappear on screen at random position also at increasing speeds` as the timer is decreasing? i.e speed of rectangles appearing and disappearing increases as the time reduces, there is a countdown time as player gets to play for 30 sec.

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;


var inc:Number = 1;
var gogo:Timer = new Timer(inc*1000);
var val:Number = 30;
var counter = val;
var time2:Timer = new Timer(1000+speed);
var speed:Number = 50;

timee.text = counter;

box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, st);

function st(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gogo.start();
    time2.start();

}

gogo.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, res);

function res(ev:TimerEvent):void

{
    if(counter == 0){
        gogo.stop();
    }else{
        val = val - inc;
        counter = val;
        timee.text = counter;
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, yea);

function yea(e:Event):void{
    speed += 50;
}
```

Comment: Heres my code so far i am even having problem as i am trying to increase timer speed as time increases and at every tick change x and y position of rectangle so will work the same and as time increases tick speed increases and so rectangle appears faster with time passing

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need a math.random() method.
[explained here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7fa1.html)

I'd personally have every successful 'hit' lower a "blinkSpeed" variable by either a set fraction of a second or a percentage and use that variable as my random input "max" number.  That way it would decrease the time it could be available for automatically as they play.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello** 
Well, that wouldn't be much hard! Here's a clue.

**Step1** : Create a new *movieclip*.

**Step2** : Right click on your movie clip in the library. Click **properties**. Check the "Export for ActionScript" checkbox. Name the class **MyEnemy** (for example).

**Step3** : Go to the frame and pull the **Actions** window.
Now put this code in it :

```
var mc:MyEnemy= new MyEnemy() // creates a instance of the movieclip.
addChild(mc); // adds the movie clip to the stage.
```

**Step 4** : Now that we have added a new movieclip to the stage. To add it at a random x location in the stage, you need to make use of mc's x and y fields and the **Math.random()** function.

Example of **Math.random()** :

```
var randomThing:Number = Math.random() * 100  // returns a number between n, where 0 <= n < 100
```

Now, for example, we need both x and y  values relative to the stage you must multiply **Math.random()** with the stage's width instead. As follows :

```
 var randomX:Number = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth // returns a number between n, where 0 <= n < stage.stageWidth

 var randomY:Number = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth // returns a number between n, where 0 <= n < stage.stageWidth
```

And! The magic final code would be :

```
 mc.x = randomX;
 mc.y = randomY;
```

**Edit 1** : To add multiple "mc" movieclips to stage, we would use loops, do the follow :

```
   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doSimple);
   function doSimple (ev:Event) {
   var mc:MyEnemy = new MyEnemy();
   var randomX:Number = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth // returns a number between n, where 0 <= n < stage.stageWidth
   var randomY:Number = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth // returns a number between n, where 0 <= n < stage.stageWidth


     for (var i:Number=1; i<=10;i++){ //i is a number, you can discard the 'i<=10' if you want an infinite loop. 

     addChild(mc);
     } 
     mc.x = randomX; 
     mc.y = randomY;
     trace("yes");
     }
```

**Conclusion** : I look forward for your feedback!